# How can I safely disable anti-malware programs on an ancillary laptop, so that I can execute risky .exe's?

Tags: installation

I bought a cheap ancillary Windows 10 laptop just for executing .exe and downloading risky files. If any file is infected with malware,  I can re-install Windows on this ancillary laptop.

When I click on an .exe to install it, the .exe file immediately vanishes. Incontrovertibly I didn't delete it! This cheap laptop must have deleted it automatically. How do I solve this?

Incontrovertibly it's too inefficient to add this .exe, and every .exe in the future, as an exception to every single anti-malware program.

Comment: Disable Windows Defender

Comment: There are download installers that delete themselves after they have started the actual installer. If something goes wrong such an installer may delete itself without having started the second stage. Therefore it doesn't have to be an anti virus software involved.

Comment: “When I click on an .exe to install it, the .exe file immediately vanishes.” - Have you checked your action center for the appropriate notifications from Windows Defender?  Have you checked Windows Defender to see if it detected the file has malware?  Was the file malware?  The literal question of what happened to the file cannot be answered by this community without some additional information

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. I [completed this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/817492). One "Ìnformation" says "Windows Defender Antivirus has taken action to protect this machine from malware or other potentially unwanted software."

Comment: If you want to run anything risky safely, just run the programmes you suspect to be malwares in a virtual machine, in this way the malwares can only infect your virtual machine, if the VM got infected just reset the VM, by sacrificing the VM your physical machine will be spared, be sure to disable the VM's network adapters first. And disable & uninstall every anti-malware software in the VM

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς No offense, but isn't your counsel dangerous and wrong? [Now, in the case that one break out of The Matrix, bad things can happen. It's not impossible, but it can be difficult.](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/w90z1/eli5_why_are_virtual_machines_generally_regarded/c5bcrty/)

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς [One of the easiest ways for this to happen is if you set up a "shared" folder than connects the VM with the host, allowing a direct connection to the host's filesystem. Alternatively, an exploit in the VM's code could cause a problem, although VMs are supposed to be completely seperate from the host.](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2itbl1/eli5how_can_a_program_running_in_a_virtual/cl5aonp/).

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς  See https://old.reddit.com/r/computerviruses/comments/jlypmo/what_will_happen_if_install_a_varus_on_a_virtual/gavoy8w/, https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/4wsfp2/eli5_why_is_opening_potentially_malicious_files/d6a1vgw/.

Comment: My advice was imprudent but not outright wrong, yes, viruses can escape the VM, however such occurrences are really rare, for precausions it's best to use a different file system and operating system in the VM and don't share any folders and disable VM network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not concerned about having an infected computer for the reasons you specify, uninstall "all anti-malware" currently installed. There should not be so many as to be cumbersome. As DavidPostill suggested in the comments, disabling Windows Defender is a good start. Identifying the remaining anti-malware programs and removing them is the next (and should be final) step.

You should ensure that this laptop is not connected to a local network, to prevent a network-savvy virus from propagating to other systems on your network.